# How can I make the program to load all text files in glob one by one?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Every time, all the operations are taking place only on the first file of glob folder..

The code is not updating the file in globs.. It's is taking only the first text file.

The code is written in the image..[image]

There is no error msg. I want it to perform same operations on all text files inside glob.

Comment: show your code as text

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also, for the love of whatever is most dear to you, please don't use single-space indentation. It's very hard to read. This is especially important with indentation-sensitive languages like Python. There are other places where judicious use of whitespace would really help make your code more readable. Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that I encourage you to read and follow.

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Finally, when you ask a question here please _stick around_ and respond to the people trying to help you in their free time. This is a two-way conversation. See [ask].

Comment: Maybe you should change indentations and run all code inside `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need to first open your writer, and then read what you need to read and write what you read in a loop . (then close your writer if you need) Not specifically your answer but should be something similar to this:

```
 with open('some.csv', 'w') as somefile:
    for filename in glob.glob('path'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file_to_read:
            some_data=file_to_read.readlines()
            #if you need loop again in data
            #or do whatever you want
            for i in range(len(some_data)):
                data=some_data[i]
                writer=csv.writer(somefile)
                writer.writerow([filename, data])
```

Comment: Here, all the files are in glob, then in "with open", what file path should I add?

Comment: I just edited, there was a small mistake. As long as you stay in the loop it will read and write one by one. @user400882

Comment: for one, I'm into the loop but still it is not reading other text file.